# Prisma does not identify field created even after migration

Tags: javascript, typescript, prisma

I have a schema in prism orm where I added the isAuthorized field, however, this field is not recognized and every time I try to make an api call that involves this field it triggers this error:

> Unknown field `isAuthorized` for select statement on model TargetGroup. Available options are listed in green.

```
model TargetGroup {

    id                       Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
    status                   Int     @default(0)
    isAuthorized             Int     @default(0)
    telegram_id              String? @db.VarChar(255)
    name                     String @db.VarChar(255)
    user_id                  String @db.VarChar(150)
    text_manipulations       String? @db.Text
    business_hours           String? @db.LongText

    bot                      Bot? @relation(fields: [bot_id], references: [id])
    bot_id                   Int?
    originGroup              OriginGroup? @relation(fields: [originGroup_id], references: [id])
    originGroup_id           Int?

    @@map("target_group")

}
```

Does anyone know what can be done to fix this?

I already tried to reinstall dependencies(npm install), add the field by hand and then pull with prism to copy the schema(npx prisma db pull), I used prism generate and nothing.

Comment: I don't know prism, but for the statement `I already tried to reinstall dependencies, add the field by hand and then pull with prism to copy the schema, I used prism generate and nothing.` it would helpful if you show what commands you tried to update the database based to the schema changed you did so that those who try to help you know what you already have tried.

Comment: Please provide your query statements or how you are using them in your code

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65663292/prisma-schema-not-updating-properly-after-adding-new-fields